# Code to change font size in Squarespace for one character

Tags: html, css, font-size, squarespace

I am helping build a friend's website in Squarespace. I am looking for a way to change the size and placing of ®.

If you look at the header that says ARISE® Intervention, the ® is as large as the rest of the word. Is that possible to change so it looks more like it does in this question I'm writing?

Here is a page that shows the issue I'm having: https://premo-castelli.squarespace.com/about/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You utilise the SUP tag to place the copyright symbol where you would usually expect to find it. That is slightly elevated and smaller than the rest of the word. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Company Name <sup>&copy;</sup></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but I just wanted to add, that if the superscript is not small enough (often it is not), you can simply make the text smaller with: `sup{font-size:8px;}`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the symbol within a `span` and give it a different font-size. Use `vertical-align: super` to use it as superscript.

```css
.symbol {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<h1>ARISE<span class="symbol">®</span> Intervention</h1>
```

Comment: You can do it a lot easier by just wrapping the registration symbol in superscript tags `<sup>&reg;</sup>`

Comment: Yes, that's right mate. I wanted to add an alternative :)